# How to make dynamically created button work like regular button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, dynamically-generated

Sorry Im a newbie programmer.
I need to know  how to create a dynamically created button that works exactly the same as a regularly created button in Javascript/JQuery, but preferably JQuery.
Here is my code.

So Here is my HTML.

```
<div>
     <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
         1.)<input type="text" name="inputVal1" style="margin-left:30px;">
         <textarea style="margin-left: 55px;"></textarea>
         <button class="btn btn-small btn-info" id="add-opt-field" style="margin-left: 12px;"></button>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="opt-field"></div>
```

And Here is my JQuery.

TL;DR it creates a lot new HTML element (but more importantly buttons with the same ID as the button in the HTML code above.

```
var n = 1;
$('button#add-opt-field').one('click', updateField);

function updateField()
{
    $('#add-opt-field').on('click',function(){

        $('#add-opt-field').attr("class", "btn btn-small btn-danger");
        $('#add-opt-field').attr("id", "rem-opt-field");
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var num = document.createTextNode(++n+".)");
        var textField = document.createElement("input");
        var textArea = document.createElement("textArea");
        var btnAdd = document.createElement("button");

        $(textField).attr("type", "text");
        $(textField).attr("name", "inputVal"+n);
        $(btnAdd).attr("class", "btn btn-small btn-info");
        $(btnAdd).attr("id", "add-opt-field");

        newDiv.appendChild(num);
        newDiv.appendChild(textField);
        newDiv.appendChild(textArea);
        newDiv.appendChild(btnAdd);
        document.getElementById("opt-field").appendChild(newDiv);

        $(newDiv).css('margin-top',30+"px");
        $(textArea).css('margin-left',60+"px");
        $(btnAdd).css('margin-left',15+"px");
        $(textField).css("margin-left", 30+"px");
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Dynamically created elements you need to use **Event delegation**

```
$(staticContainer).on('click', 'dynamicButton', updateField);
```

`staticContainer` is the elements that is already present in the DOM which is the ancestor of the newly created elements at the time the events are bound.

**Also id's in a HTML page are supposed to be unique**

So use a **class** instead of **id** wherein you can have multiple instance

Change your HTML of the button from

```
<button class="btn btn-small btn-info"
```

to

```
<button class="btn btn-small btn-info add-opt-field"
```

Also you can remove this line

```
$('button#add-opt-field').one('click', updateField);
```

Why do you want **to bind your events multiple times**

Your code should look like this

```
var n = 1;

$(staticContainer).on('click', '.add-opt-field', function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr("class", "btn btn-small btn-danger");
    $this.attr("id", "rem-opt-field");
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var num = document.createTextNode(++n+".)");
    var textField = document.createElement("input");
    var textArea = document.createElement("textArea");
    var btnAdd = document.createElement("button");

    $(textField).attr("type", "text");
    $(textField).attr("name", "inputVal"+n);
    $(btnAdd).attr("class", "btn btn-small btn-info add-opt-field");

    newDiv.appendChild(num);
    newDiv.appendChild(textField);
    newDiv.appendChild(textArea);
    newDiv.appendChild(btnAdd);
    document.getElementById("opt-field").appendChild(newDiv);

    $(newDiv).css('margin-top',30+"px");
    $(textArea).css('margin-left',60+"px");
    $(btnAdd).css('margin-left',15+"px");
    $(textField).css("margin-left", 30+"px");
});
```

**EDIT**

If the remove button is contained inside the `div` it self then you can write this up

```
$(statucContainer).on('click', '.btn-remove', function() {
     $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: OP also doesn't need both click handlers.

Comment: Like I said, Im a newbie to JQuery. Thank you so much for the advice!

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions for my code? Im going to also have to be able to delete these dynamically created div's. I was thinking about giving them a number value with a remove button that is also "id"ed with a number value, then just remove the div when the remove button is clicked.